# toLocateString doesn't give me the correct output

Tags: javascript, vue.js

toLocateString isn't working as intended, it should give me the long version of the month but instead it gives me just the number, i've tried to switch to the default and nothing changes

```
     data(){
        return{
            currentMonth: new Date().getMonth().toLocaleString("it-IT", { month: "short" }),
            
            days:['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mer','Gio','Ven','Sab'],
        }
    },
```

Comment: just try `Date().toLocaleString("it-IT", { month: "long" })`

Comment: It works but I need the month not the full date

Comment: that returns the month like `Aprile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
Date().toLocaleString("it-IT", { month: "long" })
```

because `new Date().getMonth()` returns month index